# Javascript: loop until CTRL+C is pressed

Tags: javascript, loops, keypress

How can I make a snippet of code loops until <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed?

I saw from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743533/7658051) that the indicated snippet of code loops until key <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed.

How to make it loop until <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining the indicated thread with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092839/7658051), here is a way to do it

```js
// add the event listener to catch the pressing of CTRL+C

document.body.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){

    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode; // keyCode detection
    var ctrl = e?.ctrlKey || (key === 17); // ctrl detection

    // if CTRL+C is pressed, stop the loop
    if ( key == 67 && ctrl ) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);

        console.log("Ctrl + C was pressed on the browser page (while this one was active).");
        console.log("Loop ends!");     
    }

},false);


// define the time interval that elapses between the end and the beginning of the loops
var x_milliseconds = 1000; // milliseconds

// run a function containing the loop commands, every x_milliseconds
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("The code is looping!");
}, x_milliseconds);
```

Comment: The `var ctrl` can be simplified to just `var ctrl = e?.ctrlKey || (key === 17);`